# How to validate that a selected id for a child association is unique for the parent on save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm using cocoon gem, which allows you to create multiple nested forms in a single view. The issue is, the relationship is a has_many for one side and a has_one for the other side. I would like to make it so that the has_many relationship, cannot save duplicated ids.

**facility.rb**

```
has_one :facility_administrator_connection
has_one :facility_administrator, through: :facility_administrator_connection
```

**facility_administrator.rb**

```
has_many :facility_administrator_connections
has_many :facilities, through: :facility_administrator_connection

accepts_nested_attributes :facility_administrator_connections, reject_if: :all_blank
```

**facility_administrator_connection.rb**

```
belongs_to :facility
belongs_to :facility_administrator
```

I need to verify that the same facility id isn't saved twice for the facility_administrator_connection tied to the facility administrator. There should be all unique values for the facility administrator connections when saved by the parent facility_administrator.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding what you're after, I think you should be able to accomplish that with a scoped uniqueness validation:

```rb
class FacilityAdministratorConnection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :facility
  belongs_to :facility_administrator

  validates :facility, uniqueness: { scope: :facility_administrator_id }
end
```

That will ensure when saving a connection that there can only be one `Facility` for a given `FacilityAdministrator`.

I say ensure, but you'd also likely want to define a unique index on both columns in the database to avoid unfortunate race conditions (if you use Rubocop, it will raise a `Rails/UniqueValidationWithoutIndex` cop if you use a `:uniqueness` validation without an associated unique index). That would be something like:

```
t.index ["facility_administrator_id", "facility_id"], name: "uniq_index_facility_on_facility_administrator", unique: true
```